# Можно ли некую таблицу поместить в тэг <form> для отправки на сервер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form

Есть код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
        <title>WebTest</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="ajax_form">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Your name:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name = "names" id="name" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="color">Your favourite color:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="color">
                        <option>Green</option>
                        <option>Red</option>
                        <option>Yellow</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="18-years">You are older than 18 years</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name = "you_years" id="18-years" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your favourite time of day:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-morning" name="daytime" />
                    <label for="radio-morning">Morning</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-evening" name="daytime" />
                    <label for="radio-evening">Evening</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-night" name="daytime" />
                    <label for="radio-night">Night</label>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" id = "btn" value="Send" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </form>

        <br>

        <div id="result_form"><div> 
    </body>

</html>
```

Могу ли я данную таблицу поместить в тэг  чтобы дальше уже работать с

```
$('ajax_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('ajax_form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType});});
```

Корректно ли это будет? Если нет, как мне это правильно сделать? Если да, то как мне потом вытаскивать данные из данной таблицы? Мне надо веб-приложение, которое будет отправлять данные формы на сервер используя AJAX. Столкнулся с этим 1 раз.

Comment: Если `name="daytime"`, то на сервер отправится только последнее поле. Если нужен массив, то нужно поставить `name="daytime[]"` в каждое поле

Comment: ну по идее можно же так делать? в форму помещать таблицу?

Comment: Да, ничто не запрещает)